# React-like component context in Angular2

Tags: angular

How can I do with Angular similar things I can do with React Context API? For example, something like this:

```
<>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value="red">
    <Toolbar />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
  <ThemeContext.Provider value="green">
    <Toolbar />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
</>
```

Here's working example of this: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ESWRJapMh8k9wCe9

(I've created similar boilerplate for Angular: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/OGnIpgnIsVC9wZXb. You can just provide a working fork as an answer.)

Comment: React Context API docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly but you can use ng-container & ng-content in Angualr as follows: I provide you a similar example with dynamic passed html instead of css: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvrfbm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It's not about styling or layout actually. What I want to pass down is a business logic value.

Comment: have you managed to find a solution for your problem? The only one I have found is global store and I would not like to use that technology.

Comment: You can try to achieve similar effect by "limiting provider scope with components" (see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components).

Answer (score 2):

Really I don't know what are you trying achieve. So I throw three ideas

In Angular, the components can get his "parent" in constructor using [@Host](https://angular.io/api/core/Host)

```
constructor(@Optional() @Host()parent:ParentComponent){}
```

Then, you can access to all the properties of the "ParentComponent" -the parent can be the grand parent

If you only want to use class always can defined in styles.css a css in the way (remember that styles.css is shared for all the app -is the file you use in angular.json-)

```
.red button
{
  color:red
}
.green button
{
  color:green
}
```

The other idea is that your Parent Component use [ng-content](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#single-slot-content-projection)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add 3-rd party libs please check this library. In other case you can use service.

```
https://github.com/ng-turkey/ngx-context
```